# EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES always returns eng-GBR only. Why?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using the following snippet to log all available (and unavailable) voices currently on phone:

```
ArrayList<String> availableVoices = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES);
String availStr = "";
for (String lang : availableVoices)
    availStr += (lang + ", ");
Log.i(String.valueOf(availableVoices.size()) + " available langs: ", availStr);

ArrayList<String> unavailableVoices = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_UNAVAILABLE_VOICES);
String unavailStr = "";
for (String lang : unavailableVoices)
    unavailStr += (lang + ", ");            
Log.w(String.valueOf(unavailableVoices.size()) + " unavailable langs: ", unavailStr);
```

The logged result is somehwat bewildering, since I know beyond certainty that I have multiple languages installed and I can even ***hear*** the TTS speaking in `eng-USA`, yet the log shows:

> 1 available langs: **eng-GBR**,
>
> 30 unavailable langs: ara-XXX, ces-CZE, dan-DNK, deu-DEU, ell-GRC,
>   eng-AUS, **eng-GBR**, eng-USA, spa-ESP, spa-MEX, fin-FIN, fra-CAN,
>   fra-FRA, hun-HUN, ita-ITA, jpn-JPN, kor-KOR, nld-NLD, nor-NOR,
>   pol-POL, por-BRA, por-PRT, rus-RUS, slk-SVK, swe-SWE, tur-TUR,
>   zho-HKG, zho-CHN, zho-TWN, tha-THA,

Why is this inconsistent behavior? (note that eng-GBR appears in both the available and unavailable lists...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that as far as text-to-speech in Android 2.x goes, it's the wild west out there: Every and any installed 3rd-party TTS engine can modify the output of this `EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES` function however they desire, **regardless** whether checked/unchecked or selected/unselected as default.

I just tried uninstalling all TTS engines from my phone, leaving only the hard-coded *Pico*, and the result match exactly what I expected:

> 6 available voices: deu-DEU, eng-GBR, eng-USA, spa-ESP, fra-FRA,
>   ita-ITA,
>
> 0 unavailable voices:

I don't mind the output of this function dynamically refer to the currently selected (i.e. default) TTS engine, but the fact is that once a 3rd party TTS engine is installed, this function's output doesn't make [any sense](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/3Rjd8Gen4gk), because it ignores any settings.

Also note that the name misleading: It's available **languages**, not voices!

I am posting this answer with the hope that it will help [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10524980/636571) save the time & agony of discovering this the hard way.